# VUE, in the v-for loop, how to bind each url of the loop in the style

Tags: vue.js, background, styles

{{itemA.name}}

{{itemA.name}}

:style="{ 'backgroundImage': 'url('+itemA.icon+')'}"  =》 background-image: url(./img/dashboard.svg);
This writing does not work

In the browser, the working word should be like this
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiP…AuNTk5OSIgaWQ9IkZpbGwtNyI+PC9wYXRoPgogICAgICAgIDwvZz4KICAgIDwvZz4KPC9zdmc+);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to load your image and add require functionality.

```
export default {
        methods :{
            loadImg(url){
                return require('@/' + url );
            }
        }
    }
```

Your style would be

```
:style="{'background-image': 'url(' + loadImg('+itemA.icon+') + ')'}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your approach.